# what the difference betwen mkdir vs mkdir -p

Tags: unix, command-line

I tried to create folder in my local git repo using mkdir. It didn't work, but 
`mkdir -p` works.

Why?

I'm using Mac OS by the way. I checked the definition of mkdir -p. But I still don't quite understand.

Answer (score 12):

Say you're in the directory:

```
/home/Users/john
```

And you want to make 3 new sub directories to end up with:

```
/home/Users/john/long/dir/path
```

While staying in "/home/Users/john", this will fail:

```
mkdir long/dir/path
```

You would have to make three separate calls:

```
mkdir long
mkdir long/dir
mkdir long/dir/path
```

The reason is that mkdir by default only creates directories one level down. By adding the "-p" flag, mkdir will make the entire set in one pass. That is, while this won't work:

```
mkdir long/dir/path
```

this will work:

```
mkdir -p long/dir/path
```

and create all three directories.

Answer (score 1):

From the help of mkdir:
-p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

So you failed maybe just because you wanted to create both parent and child folder in one shoot without -p option.

Answer (score 0):

That flag will create parent directories when necessary. You were probably trying to create something with subdirectories and failing due to missing the -p flag