# Saving screenshots with protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm attempting to save a screenshot using a generic method in protractor. Two features, it creates the folder if it does not exist and it saves the file (with certain conditions).

```
export function WriteScreenShot(data: string, filename: string) {
    let datetime = moment().format('YYYYMMDD-hhmmss');
    filename = `../../../test-reports/${filename}.${datetime}.png`;

    let path =filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('/'));
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(path);
    }

    let stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
    stream.end();
}
```

This can be used by calling `browser.takeScreenshot().then(png => WriteScreenShot(png, 'login/login-page'));`  Using this example call, a file will be created, I assumed, in the path relative where my WriteScreenShot method's file resides.  But that does not appear to be the case.

For example, when I run my spec test in the spec's folder, the image gets saved in the correct place.  But if I run it at the project root, an error is capture.  Obviously, this has to do with my relative path reference.  How do I capture the project's root directory and build from that so that I can run the test from any directory?

Comment: Can you give an example how and from where you run your configuration? There are several ways to do this, but the place from where you run the script can be useful to determine the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical directory access error. Let me just explain what is happening to your code -

```
 let path =filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

The above line outputs to `../../../test-reports`

`fs.existsSync` checks whether this`path` exists or not -

**case 1 :(postive flow)** Your spec folder is in the same current working directory in which you are trying to create reports folder. When you run your test, the path exists, it generates the `test-reports` directory & screenshots and your code works fine.

**case 2:(negative flow)**  When you try to run it from the root directory which is the current working directory now, `fs.existsSync` tries to check the path & the reports folder inside it. If it doesn't exist , `fs.mkdirSync` tries to create your directories but it would fail as it cannot create multiple directories.

You should be using native **path** module of nodejs to extract the path instead of using file substring and the **mkdirp** external module for creating multiple directories.

```
import * as path from 'path';
let {mkdirp} = require('mkdirp'); // npm i -D mkdirp

export function WriteScreenShot(data: string, filename: string) {
    let datetime = moment().format('YYYYMMDD-hhmmss');
    filename = `../../../test-reports/${filename}.${datetime}.png`;

    let filePath = path.dirname(filename); // output: '../../..' (relative path)
            // or
    let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname); // output: 'your_root_dir_path' (absolute path)
            // or
    let filePath = path.resolve('.'); // output: 'your_root_dir_path' (absolute path)

    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath )) {
        mkdirp.sync(filePath); // creates multiple folders if they don't exist
    }

    let stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
    stream.end();
}
```

If you are curious to know the difference btw `mkdir` & `mkdir-p` please read this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250215/what-the-difference-betwen-mkdir-vs-mkdir-p).

Comment: I also found the app-root-path module.